# How can I set c# object property value when its "get" is called

Tags: c#

I'm just trying to see if there is a way I can do this..  I have two classes. One exists as a property in the other.  So in a way its like a parent child class relationship..  The value of the child object however I want to set at this instant its "get" is called based on a value that exists in the parent object..only if it exists and isn't null.

I also don't want to set the child object if its already been set...I'm just gonna keep the mechanic as simple as possible  this is nothing more than figuring out hot to do it.

My child Class is

```
class ChildObject
    {
        public int? some_val { get; set; }

    }
```

My parent Class is

```
class ParentObject
    {
        public int? some_val { get; set; }
        public ChildObject child
        {
            get {
               //if the chld hasnt been set already
                if (child == null)
                {
                    //if the value of the integer has been set
                    if(some_val != null)
                    {
                        //some some method that sets the objects value
                        //based on teh value of the integer property
                        SomeMethod();
                    }
                }
                return child;
            }
            set { child = value;}
        }
        private void SomeMethod()
        {
            int new_val = this.some_val.Value + 5;
            this.child = new ChildObject {  some_val = new_val };
        }
    }
}
```

in some other routine..like the program of a console app or whatever I do the following

```
  ParentObject p = new ParentObject ();
            p.some_val = 1;
            ChildObject c = p.child;
            int i = c.some_val.Value;
```

Ideally I would like to add in some checks to see if the "some_val" in the parent object is changed and if so re "set" the child object...but for now Im just trying to figure out how to set the property the first time its get is called.

For some reason when I run that it just crashes.and not with any exception.  Ive tried wrapping teh routine in a try catch to see what the problem is but its just simply stops running and closes out of executing the console program.

Comment: The reason it crashes is because you have a stack overflow problem here. Your `child` property getter reads the `child` property to check for `null`. Which means that if you read the `child` property, it will read the `child` property, which will read the `child` property, which will read the `child` property, etc. Instead, add a backing field to your class and use this field inside the getter and setter instead of the property itself. Then you can tackle the actual problem you seem to want to ask about afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that when you want to add some logic to `get` or `set` methods you need to include a  field that will contain the actual value. The problem arises because you actually have an infinite loop there and getting probably a SO exception. That happens because when you get your `child` you call it's getter which it again here: `return _child;`.

```
        public int? some_val { get; set; }
        private ChildObject _child;
        public ChildObject child
        {
            get {
               //if the chld hasnt been set already
                if (_child == null)
                {
                    //if the value of the integer has been set
                    if(some_val != null)
                    {
                        //some some method that sets the objects value
                        //based on teh value of the integer property
                        SomeMethod();
                    }
                }
                return _child;
            }
            set { _child = value;}
        }
        private void SomeMethod()
        {
            int new_val = this.some_val.Value + 5;
            this.child = new ChildObject {  some_val = new_val };
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be carefull about same field or value name. You should try another value and field name. Like this;

```
private ChildObject child;
public ChildObject Child
{
    get {
       //if the chld hasnt been set already
        if (child == null)
        {
            //if the value of the integer has been set
            if(some_val != null)
            {
                SomeMethod();
            }
        }
        return child;
    }
    set { child = value;}
}
```

And you should resource to encapsulation principle.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another field to do such like so

```
    public int? some_val { get; set; }
    public ChildObject _child;
    public ChildObject child
    {
        get {
           //if the chld hasnt been set already
            if (_child == null)
            {
                //if the value of the integer has been set
                if(some_val != null)
                {
                    SomeMethod();
                }
            }
            return _child;
        }
        set { _child = value;}
    }



    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        int new_val = this.some_val.Value + 5;
        this.child = new ChildObject {  some_val = new_val };
    }
```